# error: expected initializer before '+' token

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, lcd

I made test code for my arduino to begin moving values across the screen. At the bottom of the code [int n+1 = n;], it gives the described error. Is there a good solution for this problem? Thanks.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);
int bPin = 6;
int wPin = 7;
int wTime = 30;
int bTime = 30;
int wState =0;
int bState=0;
int n = 0;
void setup(){
lcd.begin(16,2);
pinMode(bPin,INPUT);
pinMode(wPin,INPUT);
lcd.print("Ready?");

}
void loop(){
wState = digitalRead(bPin);
bState = digitalRead(wPin);
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0,n);
lcd.print("1");
lcd.setCursor(0,n+1);
lcd.print("2");
int n+1 = n;
delay(100);
}
```

`error: expected initializer before '+' token`

Comment: *is there a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think the line

```
int n+1 = n;
```

should read

```
int n = n+1;
```

Comment: I put that into the program, but when it ran, the variable never changed.

Comment: That's strange, Try something simpler to start with: `void loop(){
lcd.setCursor(0,n);
lcd.print(n);
n = n + 1;
delay(100);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Since n is already declared as a global variable in the top of your file, you should simply replace the line:

```
int n+1 = n;
```

with:

```
n += 1;
```